# CORS: why the need to categorize requests as simple?

Tags: javascript, cors

I understand the categorization of requests, but not the intent behind it. According to [Using CORS on html5rocks.com](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/):

> Simple requests are characterized as such because they can already be made from a browser without using CORS.

Does that mean that cross-domain “not-so-simple-requests” were always prohibited from being made? How did those requests work before CORS, especially HTTP CONNECT?

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that cross-domain “not-so-simple-requests” were always prohibited from being made?

Yes.

> How did those requests work before CORS, especially HTTP CONNECT?

In general, they didn't. CORS makes them possible.

CONNECT is something of a special case. It is used by proxies, so would be triggered by the browser automatically if the user has configured it to use a proxy. It isn't something a website could trigger.